# What does it mean and what are the implications of individual electrons being identical?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

In Jeremy Harvey's Computational Chemistry, I found the following statement:

> [...] all electrons need to be treated as being very strictly identical to each other, so the wavefunction cannot treat individual electrons differently.

If you could explain what the author is saying here, and what the implications are. I can't make sense of this paragraph/section. An image of the section can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOpja.jpg).

Comment: You can probably look up Slater determinants in some other textbook of your choice (preferably one with a longer explanation, because the Oxford Primers *can* be a bit terse). More fundamentally, the antisymmetric requirement stems from the [Pauli principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) (or the [spin–statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem)), and is often covered in QM textbooks under the guise of 'identical particles' or 'indistinguishable particles'. That's plenty of keywords for you to hit the library!

Comment: Thank you for replying. My aim is to go through this entire textbook as it seems like a good book to start with. My goals are to familiarise myself with computational chemistry so I can have a career in this field. I'm not very mathematically able (I am currently reading Maths for Chemistry Monk and Munro). I have looked at other books e.g. Szabo and Ostlund, Young. but found them difficult to comprehend. I'll have a look at these search terms, thank you.

Comment: What level of education are you currently at?

Comment: I have just completed an MSc Chemistry (June). I have some experience in computational chemistry (my final project was computational chemistry). However, during my MSc, this quantum chemistry stuff was done in one lecture and I think it was based more on application.

Comment: Ah, ok! I was going to say that it's easier to get into comp chem by doing it, rather than diving headfirst into the theory. But it sounds like you're at a stage where you probably should be getting into the theory if you want to pursue it further. I don't have any concrete suggestions for books, but if you aren't fully comfortable with QM, I'd probably suggest to brush up on that first.

Comment: Doing it has helped me understand things a lot better. I have a long way to go though! Looking forward to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article on [identical particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles) explains what is meant by identical particles being indistinguishable:

> There are two methods for distinguishing between particles. The first method relies on differences in the intrinsic physical properties of the particles, such as mass, electric charge, and spin. If differences exist, it is possible to distinguish between the particles by measuring the relevant properties. However, it is an empirical fact that microscopic particles of the same species have completely equivalent physical properties. For instance, every electron in the universe has exactly the same electric charge; this is why it is possible to speak of such a thing as "the charge of the electron".
>
> Even if the particles have equivalent physical properties, there remains a second method for distinguishing between particles, which is to track the trajectory of each particle. As long as the position of each particle can be measured with infinite precision (even when the particles collide), then there would be no ambiguity about which particle is which.
>
> The problem with the second approach is that it contradicts the principles of quantum mechanics. According to quantum theory, the particles do not possess definite positions during the periods between measurements. Instead, they are governed by wavefunctions that give the probability of finding a particle at each position. As time passes, the wavefunctions tend to spread out and overlap. Once this happens, it becomes impossible to determine, in a subsequent measurement, which of the particle positions correspond to those measured earlier. The particles are then said to be indistinguishable.

It also has a section on exchange symmetry that might help to see the bigger picture. Wavefunctions describing fermions (which includes electrons) have to be antisymmetric with respect to exchanging two identical particles in the wavefunction. As the article points out, this is an empirical observation. There are other particles (bosons) that don't have that requirement and have symmetric wavefunctions instead:

> [...] symmetric and antisymmetric states are essentially unchanged under the exchange of particle labels: they are only multiplied by a factor of +1 or −1, rather than being "rotated" somewhere else in the Hilbert space. This indicates that the particle labels have no physical meaning, in agreement with the earlier discussion on indistinguishability.

This requirement for antisymmetry is one way of formulating the Pauli principle. If two particles had the same (single-electron) wavefunction and the same spin, swapping them would make no difference, breaking the requirement.

Comment: What I have understood now is that electrons are identical (indistinguishable) when not measured according to QM because we are looking at wavefunctions. Thus, the equation 
       Big Psi (r1, r2 ... rn)= Small Psi1(r1) * Small Psi2(r2) * ... Psi n (rn)     is modified to accommodate the identical. So we get the equation in the picture      Big Psi (x1, x2, x3, x4) = -Big Psi (x1, x2, x3, x4)       where the negative symbol is for the antisymmetric and instead of multiplying we have combined all the psi into one overall wavefunction to show the identical (Pictured Equation). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for linking the articles and the information! This makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @PassionFruitChemistry You are most welcome. I spent some time trying to improve the quality of the question. Please think about a title that lets others find the information, too, and type the relevant quotes so they become searchable (I would have OCRed the entire page but the quality of the photo was insufficient to do that). If you feel like this answers you question fully, feel free to accept this answer. If not, you are free to edit your question to clarify what the point of confusion was. I had to guess, but judging by your comment, I guess my guess was pretty good...